# Why can I call a non-const member function pointer from a const method?

Tags: c++

A co-worker asked about some code like this that originally had templates in it.

I have removed the templates, but the core question remains: why does this compile OK?

```
#include <iostream>

class X
{
public:
     void foo() { std::cout << "Here\n"; }
};

typedef void (X::*XFUNC)() ;

class CX
{
public:
    explicit CX(X& t, XFUNC xF) : object(t), F(xF) {}      
    void execute() const { (object.*F)(); }
private:
    X& object;
    XFUNC F;
}; 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    X x; 
    const CX cx(x,&X::foo);
    cx.execute();
    return 0;
}
```

Given that CX is a const object, and its member function *execute* is const, therefore inside CX::execute the *this* pointer is const.

But I am able to call a non-const member function through a member function pointer.

Are member function pointers a documented hole in the const-ness of the world?

What (presumably obvious to others) issue have we missed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this context `object` is a *reference to a `X`*, not a *reference to a const `X`*. The `const` qualifier would be applied to the member (i.e. the reference, but references can't be `const`), not to the referenced object.

If you change your class definition to not using a reference:

```
// ...
private:
    X object;
// ...
```

you get the error you are expecting.

Comment: Still, with `const`-methods one should only be able to call `const`-methods on member-objects, isn't that right?

Comment: The member is the reference, not the referenced object.

Answer (score 12):

The `const`ness of `execute()` only affects the `this` pointer of the class.  It makes the type of `this` a `const T*` instead of just `T*`.  This is not a 'deep' const though - it only means the members themselves cannot be changed, but anything they point to or reference still can.  Your `object` member already cannot be changed, because references cannot be re-seated to point to anything else.  Similarly, you're not *changing* the `F` member, just dereferencing it as a member function pointer.  So this is all allowed, and OK.

The fact that you make your instance of CX const doesn't change anything: again, that refers to the immediate members not being allowed to be modified, but again anything they point to still can.  You can still call const member functions on const objects so no change there.

To illustrate:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    /* ... */

    int* p;

    void f() const
    {
        // member p becomes: int* const p
        *p = 5;   // not changing p itself, only the thing it points to - allowed
        p = NULL; // changing content of p in const function - not allowed
    }
};
```

Comment: It's important to notice that you can basically treat a `T&` as `T* const`. Anyway I agree that the shallow-propagation of `const` is strange, but then we also have shallow copy by default...

Answer (score 4):

The instance `object` of `class X` is not const. It is merely referenced by an object which is const. Const-ness recursively applies to subobjects, not to referenced objects.

By the alternative logic, a `const` method wouldn't be able to modify *anything*. That is called a "pure function," a concept which doesn't exist in current standard C++.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `foo` on `object`, not on `this`.

Since `object` is declared as an `X&`, in a constant CX, it is actually an `X& const` (which is not the same as `const X&`) allowing you to call non const methods on it.

Comment: I feel like you should have mentionned "X& const" is non-sensical in the langage, since there is no such thing as 'reference re-binding'.

Answer (score 0):

One helpful way of thinking about it might be that your X object is not a member of CX at all.

Comment: You could think about it like this, but it doesn't matter if it is or isn't. That class could have an X instance (`object`) as a member and also a reference member to refer to that. Then you'll find that you can't do `(object.*F)();`, but can still do `(reference.*F)();` even though it references the exact same thing that **is** a member of CX.